# Undocumented "chown user." shorthand

Tags: debian, chown

I noticed by mistake one day this undocumented shorthand for chown:

```
chown user. filename
```

Which is the shorthand for:

```
chown user:user filename
```

The latter was a real pain to type when running it often, so the shorthand came in very handy. I tried looking for its documentation in the docs but never found a hint about that hidden feature.

Is this a POSIX compliant shorthand? Is it chown that parses it differently or a bash expansion of some sort? I'm using Debian 8.4 but I've been using that for many years already. Is it debian-implementation specific?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html

Comment: @JeffSchaller Please make an answer.

Comment: I will in the morning if no one else has - but no need to wait if someone else would like to.

Comment: Also please note that `chown user: filename` will have the same effect.

Comment: In general, `chown user. filename` is _not_ the shorthand for `chown user:user filename`. That's true only if `user` happens to be the _login group_ of `user`. ([gnu chown manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html) explains)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [@JeffSchaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) for [the answer](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html).

> Some older scripts may still use ‘.’ in place of the ‘:’ separator.
>   POSIX 1003.1-2001 (see Standards conformance) does not require support
>   for that, but for backward compatibility GNU chown supports ‘.’ so
>   long as no ambiguity results. New scripts should avoid the use of ‘.’
>   because it is not portable, and because it has undesirable results if
>   the entire owner‘.’group happens to identify a user whose name
>   contains ‘.’.

This behavior is specific to GNU coreutils' chown command, and is not a function of bash. Being a GNU utility, it is also not Debian-specific.